# Make all hyperlinks in the site do nothing

Tags: javascript

I want to make a script that disables hyperlinks and instead fires a function when one is clicked.

```
<a href="http://google.com"></a>

should work as

<a onclick="talk('http://google.com)'></a>
```

Is there a way to know when the wants to redirect and instead run "talk()" or display an alert window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses (DOM Level 0) event handling instead of touching the href directly.

```
(function () {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        i = anchors.length;
    while (i--) {
        anchors[i].onclick = function () {
            talk(this.href);
            return false;
        };
    }
}());
```

Edit: The benefit of this approach is it's much simpler to put the href back when you want to. Given an anchor `tAnchor`, you merely need to unset the onclick attribute:

```
tAnchor.onclick = null
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var a = 0; a < anchors.length; a++){
  anchors[a].href = "javascript:talk('" + anchors[a].href + "');";
}
```

Use some discretion though...